# Bad side of enabling sending emails in the background?

Tags: thunderbird

Thunderbird is rather slow when sending emails. Send dialog seem to never go away. They admit that and offers an option to set sending emails in the background.

> Thunderbird does send slowly by most standards, leaving the sending dialog up until it gets a message from the server that it has the message and is sending it on. Most programs send in the background and Thunderbird can do that as well, but error reporting of transmission errors is wanting. You can enable sending in the background by setting mailnews.sendInBackground to true in the Config Editor and Thunderbird send will be much faster.

What is bad side of setting this? Does it mean that I will never be notified if there is an error in sending email?

when I enabled this I was not aware that emails were not sent and I noticed this when I started Thunderbird next time (got message if I want to sent unsent emails). This was really frightening.

Comment: You appear to have answered your own question.  What are you asking for in addition to what you have already discovered?